# inserting values into a table using python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector
import sys
from PIL import Image
import base64
import cStringIO
import PIL.Image

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='abhi',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='cbir')
sql = 'INSERT INTO fgh(id,name) VALUES(%d,%s)'    
args = (1,'abhi')
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql,args)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abhi\Desktop\cbir-p\New folder\co.py", line 16, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql,args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 472, in execute
    "Wrong number of arguments during string formatting")
ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting
```

help me solve this error

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all MySQL parameter markers should be `%s`. Try replacing the `%d` with `%s` and see if that fixes it.